# How to append number of lines in a text file to the beginning of the file?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have hundreds of text files in a folder. I am looking for a way to append number of lines in a text file to the beginning of the corresponding text file? Any idea, how to do this quickly for all the files in the folder using Bash?

Comment: Why do you think you need the line count at the start of the file? Does the line count include the the line with the count, or is it the number of lines after the line count?  Generally, you should be aiming to read until EOF, not messing around with predetermined numbers of lines.  What is your code going to do if the file is modified after the line count is added, either by (partial) truncation or by being extended?

Comment: Line count should bn number of lines after the line count. I am using it to pre-allocate memory for the feature vectors following the line count.

Comment: I was suspicious that you were wanting the line count so you knew how much data is in the rest of the file. A line count before data is useful for novice programmers who don't know dynamic memory allocation because it avoids some problems, but I recommend that you learn how to do dynamic memory allocation incrementally, adding to your structure as you go. Tip: the way you don't do it is by using `realloc()` to increment the size by one on each new line. For arrays, you will typically allocate twice as many entries each time you need more memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
for file in *.txt; do
    tmp=$(mktemp -dt "${file}")
    < ${file} wc -l | cat - ${file} > ${tmp}
    mv ${tmp} ${file}
done
```

Or if you want to do it in parallel:

```
function AddLineCount {
    tmp=$(mktemp -dt "$1")
    < $1  wc -l | cat - $1 > ${tmp}
    mv ${tmp} $1
}

# With a parallelism of 10
# Assuming your disk has the iops for it.
ls *.txt | xargs -P10 -I^ AddLineCount ^
```

#### Update

Modifying file without creating a new one. This relies on some properties of sed which is not a bash built-in and sometime varies between versions. The current command works on my mac

```
sed -i -e "1s/^/$( wc -l fileName | awk '{print $1}')\\
/" fileName
```

So doing it in a loop:

```
for file in *.txt; do

    sed -i -e "1s/^/$(wc -l ${file} | awk '{print $1}')\\
/" ${file}

done
```

Comment: I did not want to create a new file, even if temp, in my answer but your parallel example is very nice.

Comment: @MattGreen: YOu may have wanted to mention that in the question. Updated in one second.

Comment: [Useless use of `cat`](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html)! You can write `<"$file" wc -l` instead.

Comment: @GarethRees: Guilty of much worse. But fixed to make sure it is good for SO.

Answer (score 1):

The following will do just that with the approriate substitution for the grep to insure you work on the right files.

```
for i in $(ls |grep ".txt") ; do c=$(wc -l < $i) ; sed -i '1s/^/$c\n /' $i ; done
```

/$c\n/ is what is appended so you can do /LINECOUNT: $c\n/ , but keep the \n so the previous first line is not appended to but moved to the second line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the solution provided here - It works for one file, but you can place it in loop for the desired list of files.

[Add text to top of file](https://superuser.com/questions/246837/how-do-i-add-text-to-the-beginning-of-a-file-in-bash)

Alternatively, you could write a program to do the task.

I suggest that you output the result to a separate folder and not overwrite the original files at first in case of a bug occurs, also test the approach for empty files or files where you don't have rights to access.